# How to instantiate an interface object with implementation that is passed in to current method in C#?

Tags: c#, dynamic, interface, instantiation, typeof

Given a simple interface

```
public interface IIdTracker
{
    int Id { get; }
}
```

And I have two class that implements it

```
public class human : IIdTracker
{
    public int Id { return 0; }
}

public class robot : IIdTracker
{
    public int Id { return 1; }
}
```

How can I instantiate whatever the class that is passed as IIdTracker without any knowledge of who or what is implementing IIdTracker?

```
public void TrackId(IIdTracker idt)
{
    // this is the code I am not sure of
    var being = new idt.GetType();
}
```

Comment: Do you need a new instance of an `IIdTracker`? You already *have* an instance in `idt`.

Comment: Yes I wanted separate IIdTracker, but I wanted the type that is passed in.

Comment: You might be able to create a new instance with reflection (or via new generic constraint), but do you want it to return the same Id value?

Answer (score 2):

After some research, I found

```
var being = Activator.CreateInstance(idt.GetType()) as IIdTracker;
```

as a solution.

Answer (score 2):

A better way to do this using generics would be:

```
    public void TrackId<T>(T idt)
        where T:IIdTracker, new()
    {
        var being = new T();
    }
```

and add a public parameterless constructor to your classes, e.g.

```
public class Human : IIdTracker
{
    public Human() { }
    public int Id { return 0; }
}
```

Alternatively, if, as your edit says you cannot do this because ultimately you end up with a `List` of `IIdTracker` objects that you are trying to clone, then a better approach may be to add a `.Clone` method into your `IIdTracker` interface, or create a new interface `IIdCloneable` so that humans or robots each know how to create clones of themselves. Or, instead you have a `CloneFactory` and each type registers itself with the clone factory so it knows how to create one of anything.  The clone factory could be as simple as a `Dictionary<Type,Func<IIdTracker>>` which stores actions to create humans, robots or whatever. e.g. `factory.Add(typeof(Human), () => new Human());`

Comment: In order for this to work compiler tells me that my IIdTracker has to have parameterless constructor. But it is interface... would this only work with abstract class?

Comment: @publicst119 The generic constraints enforce that `T` is both a class that implements `IIdTracker` and has a parameterless constructor (this is the `new()` constraint in the method definition). Neither your method not this one creates an "instance of `IIdTracker`", they're both creating an instance of a class that implements `IIdTracker`.

Comment: @publicst119 I added some code per Preston's comments showing what you need to do.

Comment: I am aware that neither of our solution is creating instance of `IIdTracker`. Which is fine. However, when I constrain using `where T:IIdTracker, new()` my compiler throws error at the location where it is calling `TrackId<T>` stating that `idt` has to have parameterless constructor. Implementation of the interface does have parameterless constructor but it is outside of this projects knowledge.

Comment: @publicst119 Yes, the generic will propagate out through your solution, if you are calling this from another method that takes IIdTracker you will need to fix it there too and make that method generic also. Or perhaps you make the whole class generic and then the methods don't need to be generic.

Comment: @IanMercer So what if I trace it up and eventually it gets to the collection of `<IIdTracker>` (which contains both `human` and `robot` mixed together inside)? In that case, I cannot specify what exactly T is...

Comment: @publicst119 In that case you are somewhat stuffed because your object isn't really a robot or a human; it's a robot + a robot factory or a human + a human factory. So maybe you should make it one of those explicitly instead and give it a .Clone() method as part of the interface.  human.Clone() makes another human etc.